# Magento 2 slow open categories and products

Tags: magento-2.1, php, database, nginx, varnish

Help me please understand, why my store is working slowly on Magento 2.1.1. Ubuntu x64, DO 16cpu, 48Gb ram, ssd. We use nginx, php-fpm 7.0, varnish 4, mysql 5.6.

This is very strange situation for me because i have another magento 2 store with 8 cpu with same env, and it work well. We got about 3000 products id DB.

Answer (score 1):

James Maynard,

### Slowness of product and category depends on few elements:

- 1.**`Check Catagory and product flat setting enable at admin.it should be enable.**
- 2.**Check how many attributes  enable Show In product listing. it make less.**
- 3.**Third party extensions quality.it most case, i have seen that 3rd pary extension is make site speed slow.**
- 4.**Indexing issue,Check your Index management is working perfectly.**
- 5.**Suggest to upgrade at magento 2.2.x version.**

You should check above reason to optimized your site.

Comment: thank you for your answer. tell me more about 4 point please. What do you mean.

Comment: First check  http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/index-management.html , http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

Comment: Some time index management is not working  and show process  processing status always or showing error when try  to indexing it. Need to resolve those  issues

Comment: Tell me please. We got 100k of products, and main problem is that products open very slow, also in admin panel create or delete products and categories also very slow, and sometimes even got 503 error from varnish. we got 16 cpu \ 48 ram server for this. there is about 50 clients.

Comment: what  type of cache storage   you are  using ? redis/memcache?

Comment: we use redis server